# 1723 port isn't opened after setting up an incoming connection on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-10

I have set up my VPN server/incoming connection as this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

I can connect to the server computer(where I set up the incoming connection) using remote desktop but can not connect to it using VPN connection.

When I am trying to connect to the server computer by VPN, I got error code 868 immediately.

I have tried telnet and got the surprised result:

```
C:\Users\paleneutron>telnet 127.0.0.1 1723
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1723: Connect failed
```

These code fails even I closed my firewall.

It seems the 1723 port isn't opened!

**I have tried the same steps on a Windows 7 machine, everything works fine.**

Where is the problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The link you provided contains multiple guides, which one is it specifically? "PPTP VPN Server Set Up," "VPN Router Set Up," "PPTP VPN Client Set Up," or "VPN Connection"?

Also, can you please identify where you are getting the error code from or, alternatively, take a screen cap of it?

Comment: @IfOnlyIHadAGoodUsername , I have changed the link pointing to HTG. The guide I mean is "PPTP VPN Server Set Up", I do not know how to up load a screen shot _(:зゝ∠)_, I got the error code when using VPN connection in windows to connect to my server computer.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. You can take a screenshot by searching up "Snipping Tool" on your computer, and then upload it to **http://imgur.com/**. Are you setting up the server _and_ connecting to it on the same machine? Because according to **[this](https://goo.gl/dD2MD5)**, it might be. "[The] name of the remote access server did not resolve" is the _old_ name of the error, so this could be a DNS problem in particular. Try adding the IP address of your router/gateway to your DNS as a secondary. Alternatively, try [flushing the DNS cache](http://goo.gl/3OalZm).

Comment: @IfOnlyIHadAGoodUsername, after a lot of work I have made the problem much more specific. Port 1723 does not opened after I set up an incoming connection on Win 10.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue after updating Windows 10 to 1709.  To correct the issue ensure that the service Remote Access Auto Connection Manager is running.

1. Open the task manager
2. Select the services tab
3. Look for either the name RasAuto or description Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
4. Once the service is running, open a command prompt
5. Run the command netstat -a | more and confirm that TCP 0.0.0.0:1723 is listening

I hope this helps

Comment: For Windows 10, Maybe it has a bug so after starting Remote Access Auto Connection Manager, nothing changed (nothing listening at port 1723).
But when I try to make a fresh restart Windows, It worked!

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 11, open your Task Manager and in tab Service.
Make sure RasAuto and RasMan are in Running status.
Also, **RemoteAccess** has to be in Running status.
Try to test the port after https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is essentially the same thing as the better answer above, plus a link of dubious purpose and value.

Comment: Yea. I tried but not allowed  to reply to a comment, because I am a new user.